# Use screen.width inside calc (css)

Tags: css, width, screen, calc

Is there a was of using `screen.width` inside `calc`? Something like this:

```
 left: calc(250px + screen.width - 1024px)!important;
```

It is for a concrete situation where the @media(max-width: 1024px) won't work.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

*100vw = 100% of viewport width*

```
left:calc(250px + 100vw - 1024px)!important;
```

Comment: Note that `vw` is the width of the *viewport* (browser window), while the question asks about `screen.width` which is the width of the *screen*. So the results will be different if the window is not maximised. (To be fair, in most cases you probably want the viewport width rather than screen width; but that's not what the question is asking.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `vw` units to size things in relation to viewport width, so try this:

```
left: calc(250px + 100vw - 1024px) !important;
```

Answer (score 2):

`left: calc(250px + 100vw - 1024px)!important;` this probably won't work I would do it like this: `calc(100vw - 774px);` (1024 - 250 = 774)

`vw` - view width

Comment: why do you think calc(250px + 100vw - 1024px) won't work? (it does)