# CSS: Is there a shorter way to write multiple media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is the code I've written out, but there has to be a more condensed, elegant, and effective way to write media queries for scaling screens, right?

```
selector { padding-left: 19% }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  selector { padding-left: 17% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1420px) {
  selector { padding-left: 17% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1480px) {
  selector { padding-left: 16.5% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1520px) {
  selector { padding-left: 16% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1585px) {
  selector { padding-left: 15.5% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1620px) {
  selector { padding-left: 15% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1720px) {
  selector { padding-left: 14% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1820px) {
  selector { padding-left: 13% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  selector { padding-left: 12% }
}
```

Comment: My first question to the designer would be 'is this level of accuracy really going to make a difference to the user's experience of the page?' - especially since the values calculated result in a step function rather than something continuous - why bother?

Comment: @AHaworth OP here. It's hard to tell if it's worth the trouble when there's no context. And the step-function is just sloppy design on my part. I'm rewriting it to be linear instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change padding based on the screen-width scaling **linearly** between 1420px and 1920px from 17% to 12%, you can use `calc` to calculate the growing proportion of padding based on the current screen size. (Though in your example it's not exactly linear between these two points, it seems like that's what you're trying to achieve as shown in the graph below.)

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.padding-box {
  padding-left: 19%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1420px) {
  .padding-box {
    padding-left: calc(17% - (100vw - 1420px) * (17 - 12) / (1920 - 1420));
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  .padding-box {
    padding-left: 12%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="padding-box">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask how you came up with the calc expression? I can't wrap my head around what's being subtracted from 17%

Comment: This is basically a segment of a linear equation between x and y between two points (1420, 17) and (1920, 12), where x is the current screen width and y is the padding. There are formulas out there for this but really we're just trying to express how much y should change when x changes.

Comment: `100vw` is the current screen width, hence `(100vw-1420px)` means how much x increases from `1420px`. It's multiplied by `-(17-12)/(1920-1420)`, which is the slope (how much y should increase (or decrease since the slope is negative) when x increases).  Note that when I say screen width I'm talking about viewport width (browser screen).

Answer (score -1):

You can combine similar values and reduce
last set of media queries, the padding value had a bit of variation, so I used the `calc()` function to handle it.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  selector { padding-left: 17% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1420px),
       only screen and (min-width: 1480px) {
  selector { padding-left: 16.5% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1520px),
       only screen and (min-width: 1585px),
       only screen and (min-width: 1620px) {
  selector { padding-left: 16% }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1720px),
       only screen and (min-width: 1820px),
       only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  selector { padding-left: calc(14% - 1%); }
}
```

Comment: You may also use the width for a calculation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591449/use-screen-width-inside-calc-css

Comment: I don't understand the point of the calc - doesn't it always end up at 13%?

Comment: @AHaworth the computed values is always 13%, but it depends on the width of the container, the available space, and any other CSS rules affecting the padding, the final rendered value may vary depending on the context.

Comment: Yes, the final rendered value may indeed change, but calc(14% - 1%) always renders as 13% - there is no point in spelling it out as 14% - 1%

Comment: Thank you! Your answer taught me 2 things: it's possible to combine media queries, and that the calc() function exists